# Proper use of color_bar in formattable in order to export it to pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, colorbar, formattable

I need to use nice formattable with icons, icontext, color_bar, etc in a pdf. The only available option I have found is the one I present in the following code. I just output the table as an image using webshot and then insert it in my document.

However, all works perfectly when I am working with positive values (but as you can see the bar goes from the right to the left even when these are positive values):

```
library("htmltools")
library("webshot")  
library(formattable)
DF <- data.frame(Ticker=c("", "", "", "IBM", "AAPL", "MSFT"),
                 Name=c("Dow Jones", "S&P 500", "Technology", 
                        "IBM", "Apple", "Microsoft"),
                 Value=accounting(c(15988.08, 1880.33, 50, 
                                    130.00, 97.05, 50.99)),
                 Change=percent(c(-0.0239, -0.0216, 0.021, 
                                  -0.0219, -0.0248, -0.0399)))

################################## FUNCTIONS ##################################
unit.scale = function(x) (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
export_formattable <- function(f, file, width = "100%", height = NULL, 
                               background = "white", delay = 0.2)
    {
      w <- as.htmlwidget(f, width = width, height = height)
      path <- html_print(w, background = background, viewer = NULL)
      url <- paste0("file:///", gsub("\\\\", "/", normalizePath(path)))
      webshot(url,
              file = file,
              selector = ".formattable_widget",
              delay = delay)
    }
###############################################################################

FT <- formattable(DF, align =c("l","c","r","c"), list(
  Name=formatter("span", 
                 style = x ~ ifelse(x == "Technology", style(font.weight = "bold"), NA)), #NOT APPLIED when we output to PNG with the function!
  #Value = color_tile("white", "orange"),
  Value = color_bar("orange" , fun = unit.scale
                    ),
  Change = formatter("span", 
                     style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x < 0 , "red", "green"), "font.size" = "18px"), 
                     x ~ icontext(ifelse(x < 0, "arrow-down", "arrow-up"), x)
                     )),
  table.attr = 'style="font-size: 18px;";\"')

FT
#OUTPUT the table in the document as an image!
export_formattable(FT,"thePATH/FT.png")
```

[image]

So the very first question is:

1.How do I switch the bars to the right? Positive values should go to the right and negative to the left, thus the numbers should start in the horizontal axis to the right if they are positive, and to the left if they are negative. Always inside over the bars.

2. The second question is way more trickier, if I just replace a negative value in the dataframe I obtain the number in a werid format, a parenthesis is added!!!

```
#If I just put a negative symbol I obtain the numbers but not as negative but a parenthesis goes in!
DF <- data.frame(Ticker=c("", "", "", "IBM", "AAPL", "MSFT"),
                 Name=c("Dow Jones", "S&P 500", "Technology", 
                        "IBM", "Apple", "Microsoft"),
                 Value=accounting(c(-15988.08, -1880.33, -50, 
                                    -130.00, -97.05, -50.99)),
                 Change=percent(c(-0.0239, -0.0216, 0.021, 
                                  -0.0219, -0.0248, -0.0399)))
```

Also notice how the bars do mess up:

[image]

In another variation I did by putting up negative values the chart displays exactly as the first one with negative values! just modifying the unit.scale function as well. but the problem now is the negative sign goes funny to the right of the number (this does not happen if you run the chunk in Rmarkdown, but only when you produce the PDF!), so in the pdf i obtain the following, if you wanna reproduce please check the pdf file not the chart in Rstudio:

```
#only modification to the previous code:
unit.scale = function(x) (x - max(x)) / (min(x) - max(x))
```

this is shown when I run the chunk in RStudio:

[image]

but when I open the pdf:

[image]

My ultimate goal is to produce the following color_bars and being able to export them to the pdf file.

[image]

Thanks in advance!